# Measuring temperature using resistance termometer Pt100

Tags: power, current, measurement, temperature, output

[image]

Given:

- voltage source \$U_0\$ = 1.2 V
- \$R_i = 1000 \Omega\$
- \$Pt_{100}\$ is described by \$\Delta\delta=T-T_0=0°C\$ with \$R_0 =100  \Omega\$ at \$0°C\$
- \$R_1 = 500 \Omega, R_2 = 50 \Omega\$

Asked:

- Calculate the \$I_{out}\$ at the amplifier for \$0°C\$ and \$100°C\$

\$R = {\rho L \over A} = 50 \Omega = R_{L1} = R_{L2} = R_{L3}\$

\$R_{0°C}=R_i+R_{L1}+R_{Pt0°C}+R_{L3}=1200\Omega\$

\$I_{0°C}={U_0\over R_{0°C}}=1mA\$

\$Uc_{0°C} = I_{0°C} (R_{Pt0°C}+R_{L3})= 0.15 A\$

\$I_{out} = {U_c\over R_{L2}}=3mA\$

- Calculate the general transfer characteristic - thus, the \$I_{out}\$ of the amplifier as a function of temperature.

I've found the solution for 0°C, but I don't know how to calculate it at \$100°C\$ (because I don't know the \$R_0\$ at \$100°C\$).

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I think all your answers will be expressions and not just numbers. In your first answer, why did you ignore RL1/3? Similarly, at 100 C you can write an expression. For the power you need to find the current though the 3 elements and then use I^2*Rx where Rx is the sensor resistance at temperature, or the voltage V across the sensor and use V^2/Rx,

Comment: Thanks, now I use \$P = R I^2\$ to find power. From my updated post, you can see my calculation for 0°C. But for 100°C, I don't know what to to input in \$R_{Pt0°C}\$ part. Also I'm not sure, which resistor do I have to use in \$U_c\$ (input voltage) and \$I_{out}\$ part.

Comment: You can use 138.5 ohms for DIN standard Pt100 @100°C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pt100 resistance vs temperature is defined by various standards. Here's one.

[image]

*Figure 1. Extract from [Labfacility](https://www-zeuthen.desy.de/~wischnew/pamela/internal/daq/Thermal_Sensors/pt100_datasheet.pdf) datasheet.*

Figure 1 shows that at 100°C the resistance will be 138.51 Ω.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer if it did, in fact, answer your question.